# Number, currency and date filter

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I would like to learn how to filter number, currency and date columns. My currency example code is:

```
Private Sub HavaleSrcBtn_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles HavaleSrcBtn.MouseDown

    Me.MakbuzTBindingSource.Filter = "havaleTutari LIKE '%" & HavaleSrcTb.Text & "%'"

End Sub
```

This code makes the program crashed: Cannot perform 'Like' operation on System.Decimal and System.String. The whole details are here: http://sudrap.org/paste/text/256246/

I'm using Visual Basic 2012. How can I filter these kinds of data?

Edit:

```
Me.MakbuzTBindingSource.Filter = "havaleTutari = '" & CStr(HavaleSrcTb.Text) & "'"
```

This works fine but I can't use wildcards:

```
Me.MakbuzTBindingSource.Filter = "havaleTutari = 'ANY " & CStr(HavaleSrcTb.Text) & " ANY'"
```

Comment: could you share a bit more. we have no idea what `MakbuzTBindingSource` could possibly be. You aren't sharing your exception log neither.

Comment: I added the error message. I don't know what to tell about MakbuzTBindingSource. It's a table binding source. My database is a simple mdb database. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Cannot perform 'Like' operation on System.Decimal and System.String.

Answer (score 1):

`LIKE` is only for character string (text) data. It is not possible to have a number `LIKE` another number, clearly. (What would a number `LIKE 1` be? `1.1`? `10`?)

For numeric, currency and date columns, use `>`, `>=`, `=`, `<=`, `<`, or `BETWEEN Value1 AND Value2`.

(You could also try reading the documentation, which states this pretty clearly. It's also important to note that `Visual Studio` is not a programming language. If your question is about `VB.NET`, use the `VB.NET` tag. If it's specific to a MS-Access database, use the `ms-access` tag.)

I don't think you need `CStr` either. A simple string concatenation should work just fine:

```
Me.HavaleScrTb.Text = '100'
Me.MakbuzTBindingSource.Filter = "havaleTutari = " & HavaleSrcTb.Text
```

Comment: thank you for the detailed answer. i corrected the tags. can you give me an example code?

Comment: I'm not sure what "example code" you're looking for; I provided all of the information for you to just put into your code. What more do you need? (I don't use VB.NET, I don't have your tables, and I don't know anything about the datatypes of the columns. I'm also not sure how you plan to have `Mouse_Down` apply a filter. Do you want a new filter to take place every time the mouse button is pressed? If I was your user, I'd be very irritated after about half a second of trying to use your app.)